# What can we say about a vector space with an only base?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

The rank of the vector system is $r$. What can we say about that system if it has only one base?

Comment: The only vector spaces with a single basis are the trivial vector space or over the field of two elements.

Comment: To emphasize what was said, you should be aware of how you have $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ as a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ (*over the reals*).  But, you also have $\{(2,0),(0,2)\}$ is *also* a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ and so is $\{(x,0),(0,y)\}$ for any of the infinitely many different choices of $x$ and $y$ so long as neither are zero.  Well... the same is true even for one-dimensional spaces too... $\{(1)\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^1$ (*over the reals*) but so too is $\{(2)\}$ and $\{(x)\}$ for each other $x$.  That's not even getting started with how $\{(1,1),(-1,1)\}$ and other ways of "mixing" basis can be

Comment: The only ways of ensuring there is only one possible base for a vector space is by either making it dimension zero (*since there is exactly one way to write a collection of zero things*)... or by looking at vector spaces who are over a finite field, specifically one with only a single unit which only happens for $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Isn't $((1,0),(1,1))$ a basis for $\Bbb F_2^2$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yeah you're right. This is what I get for trying to think in the morning.